# Appication using Room Database getting "unused parameter error" on build

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error when building my project using a Room Database.

C:\Users\russelg1\AndroidStudioProjects\CheckingIn\app\src\main\java\com\grgsolutions\checkingin\CheckInTableDao.java:19: error: Unused parameter: checkInTablePrimaryKey
    List findCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey);

**This is the DAO for the table in question**

```
package com.grgsolutions.checkingin;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import java.util.List;
@Dao
public interface CheckInTableDao {
    @Insert
    void insertCheckIn(CheckInTable... checkInTable);

    @Query("DELETE FROM check_in_table WHERE checkInTablePrimaryKey = :checkInTablePrimaryKey")
    void deleteCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM check_in_table")
    LiveData<List<CheckInTable>> getAllCheckIn();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM check_in_table where checkInTablePrimaryKey = checkInTablePrimaryKey")
    List<CheckInTable> findCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey);

    @Query("DELETE FROM check_in_table")
    void deleteAllCheckIn();

}
```

This is the Room Repository for the table.

```
package com.grgsolutions.checkingin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.text.PrecomputedText;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import java.util.List;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class CheckInTableRepository {

    private MutableLiveData<List<CheckInTable>> searchCheckInResults =
            new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<List<CheckInTable>> allCheckIn;
    private List<CheckInTable> foundCheckIn;
    private CheckInTableDao checkInTableDao;

    public CheckInTableRepository(Context appContext) {
        CheckingInRoomDatabase db;
        db = CheckingInRoomDatabase.getDatabase(appContext);
        checkInTableDao = db.checkInTableDao();
        allCheckIn = checkInTableDao.getAllCheckIn();
        foundCheckIn = checkInTableDao.findCheckIn(0);

    }

    public LiveData<List<CheckInTable>> getAllCheckIn() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllCheckIn: creating allCheckIn ");
        return allCheckIn;
    }


    public void insertCheckIn(CheckInTable newcheckin) {
        CheckInTableRepository.InsertAsyncTask task = new
                CheckInTableRepository.InsertAsyncTask(checkInTableDao);
        task.execute(newcheckin);
    }

    public void deleteCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey) {
        CheckInTableRepository.DeleteAsyncTask task = new
                CheckInTableRepository.DeleteAsyncTask(checkInTableDao);
        task.execute();
    }

    public CheckInTable findCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey) {
        CheckInTableRepository.QueryAsyncTask task = new
                CheckInTableRepository.QueryAsyncTask(checkInTableDao);
        task.delegate = this;
        task.execute(checkInTablePrimaryKey);
    }

    private void asyncFinished(List<CheckInTable> result) {
        foundCheckIn = result;
    }

    private static class QueryAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<CheckInTable>> {

        private CheckInTableDao asyncTaskDao;
        private CheckInTableRepository delegate = null;

        QueryAsyncTask(CheckInTableDao dao) {
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<CheckInTable> doInBackground(final Integer... params) {
            return asyncTaskDao.findCheckIn(params[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(List<CheckInTable> result) {
            delegate.asyncFinished(result);
        }
    }
    private static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<CheckInTable, Void, Void> {
        private CheckInTableDao asyncTaskDao;
        InsertAsyncTask(CheckInTableDao dao) {
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final CheckInTable... params) {
            asyncTaskDao.insertCheckIn(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        private CheckInTableDao asyncTaskDao;
        DeleteAsyncTask(CheckInTableDao dao) {
            asyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Integer... params) {
            asyncTaskDao.deleteCheckIn(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the View Model**

```
package com.grgsolutions.checkingin;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private CheckInRecipientsTableRepository checkInRecipientsTableRepository;
    private LiveData<List<CheckInRecipientsTable>> allRecipients;

    private ContactGroupsTableRepository contactGroupsTableRepository;
    private LiveData<List<ContactGroupsTable>> allContactGroups;

    private ContactTableRepository contactTableRepository;
    private LiveData<List<ContactTable>> allContacts;

    private CheckInTableRepository checkInTableRepository;
    private LiveData<List<CheckInTable>> allCheckIn;
    private List<CheckInTable> foundCheckIn;


    public MainViewModel (Context appContext) {
        //super(appContext);

        Log.i(TAG, "MainViewModel: In the Main View Model");

        checkInRecipientsTableRepository = new CheckInRecipientsTableRepository(appContext);
        allRecipients = checkInRecipientsTableRepository.getAllCheckInRecipients();

        Log.i(TAG, "MainViewModel: In the Main View Model");

        checkInTableRepository = new CheckInTableRepository(appContext);
        allCheckIn = checkInTableRepository.getAllCheckIn();

        //checkInTableRepository = new CheckInTableRepository(appContext);
        //foundCheckIn = checkInTableRepository.findCheckIn();

        Log.i(TAG, "MainViewModel: In the Main View Model");

        contactGroupsTableRepository = new ContactGroupsTableRepository(appContext);
        allContactGroups = contactGroupsTableRepository.getAllContactGroups();

        Log.i(TAG, "MainViewModel: In the Main View Model");

        contactTableRepository = new ContactTableRepository(appContext);
        allContacts = contactTableRepository.getAllContact();

    }
    LiveData<List<CheckInTable>> getAllCheckIn() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllCheckIn:  in main view model");
        return allCheckIn;
    }
    public void findCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey) {
        checkInTableRepository.findCheckIn(checkInTablePrimaryKey);
    }
    public void insertCheckIn(CheckInTable checkInTable) {
        checkInTableRepository.insertCheckIn(checkInTable);
    }
    public void deleteCheckIn(int checkInTablePrimaryKey) {
        checkInTableRepository.deleteCheckIn(checkInTablePrimaryKey);
    }

    LiveData<List<CheckInRecipientsTable>> getAllCheckInRecipients() {
        return allRecipients;
    }

    public void insertCheckInRecipientsTable(CheckInRecipientsTable checkInRecipientsTable) {
        checkInRecipientsTableRepository.insertCheckInRecipientsTable(checkInRecipientsTable);
    }
    public void deleteCheckInRecipient(int checkInPrimaryKey) {
        checkInRecipientsTableRepository.deleteCheckInRecipient(checkInPrimaryKey);
    }
    public void deleteCheckInRecipientForCheckIn(int checkInPrimaryKey) {
        checkInRecipientsTableRepository.deleteCheckInRecipientForCheckIn(checkInPrimaryKey);
    }
    public void findCheckInRecipient(int checkInPrimaryKey) {
        checkInRecipientsTableRepository.findCheckInRecipient(checkInPrimaryKey);
    }

    LiveData<List<ContactGroupsTable>> getAllContactGroups() {
        return allContactGroups;
    }

    public void insertContactGroupsTable(ContactGroupsTable contactGroupsTable) {
        contactGroupsTableRepository.insertContactGroups(contactGroupsTable);
    }
    public void deleteContactGroups(int contactGroupsTablePrimaryKey) {
        contactGroupsTableRepository.deleteContactGroups(contactGroupsTablePrimaryKey);
    }
    public void findContactGroups(int contactGroupsTablePrimaryKey) {
        contactGroupsTableRepository.findContactGroups(contactGroupsTablePrimaryKey);
    }

    LiveData<List<ContactTable>> getAllContact() {
        return allContacts;
    }

    public void insertContactTable(ContactTable contactTable) {
        contactTableRepository.insertContact(contactTable);
    }
    public void deleteContact(int contactTablePrimaryKey) {
        contactTableRepository.deleteContact(contactTablePrimaryKey);
    }
    public void findContact(int contactTablePrimaryKey) {
        contactTableRepository.findContact(contactTablePrimaryKey);
    }


}
```

Comment: you are missing the `:` in the query to reference the `checkInTablePrimaryKey` parameter. Take a look at how it's done in `deleteCheckIn`.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it a dozen times.